# Do sectors build synthetics?

Tags: stellaris

So i decided to check out the playable robots mod and go full synthetic, meaning that any pops i build will not consume any food(energy instead) but don't breed, ever.

So far it's going slowly but steadily, i built up my core planets and just started to create sectors but it seems that there aren't any new pops on planets in those sectors. This might be because the sector economy is still pretty small scale and the sector government is unwilling to invest in more pops right now or the ai is not even considering building synthetics... i'd like to know which one it is.

So if anyone has experience with this: please share your insight because i'd rather not just wait and see.

**update:** it seems the playable robots mod was upgraded to include a policy which allows sector governments to build robots, so *with* this mod sectors will build synthetics if you activate the policy(costs 0 diplomatic capital iirc)

Comment: It's all fun and games until someone asks if they have a soul.

Comment: @Studoku they got something better, fanatic materialism and citizen rights x)

Comment: @Studoku do they have a soul?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my personal experience, no they don't. I have several planets colonized by a synth in sectors and even 50 years later there still is only one pop on the planet.

Comment: Same for me, It might be fixed in the following updates - they focus heavily on sector AI

Comment: That's what i thought ... anyway, i guess there's something good in this after all since we can build pops on sector planets and actually use that, coupled with free migration, to slowly populate all sectors by building pops on empty planets which will eventually spread everywhere and fill the gaps.